# How to set form validation for different values of radio buttons

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a form with 3 radio buttons  for my register form - users could choose one of 3 user roles. If you choose first radio button, you see following dropdowns: region, school, teacher, class and class divisions, for radio button 2 - you see the first dropdowns but without teacher. If you choose 3-rd radio button, you see checkboxes with all teachers. 
I show and hide dropdowns dependent on user choice. 
How to make form validation - if it is chosen first radio button, to show only these form validation rules that are for that radio button. And so on for the three radio buttons. My controller is:

```html
public function register()
    {
        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');  
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('school[]', 'School', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class[]', 'Class', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_id', 'Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_divisions[]', 'Class division', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('teacher[]', 'Teacher', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('all_teachers_show', 'All teachers', 'required');
     
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->signup();
        }
        else 
        {  
            if( $this->user_model->register())
            {
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'success_reg'; 
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->model('user_model');   
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'register_form'; 
                $data['regions'] = $this->user_model->regions_show();
                $data['classes'] = $this->user_model->classes_show();
                $data['school_show'] = $this->user_model->school_show();
                $data['class_divisions'] = $this->user_model->class_divisions_show();
                $data['all_teachers_show'] = $this->user_model->all_teachers_show();
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }   
        }
    }
```

My view is:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>   
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       
        <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(":radio").click(function(){
              $('#region').val('Choose region');
              $('#school').val('Choose region');
              $('#teacher').val('Choose school');
              $('#class').val('Choose class');
              $('#class_divisions').val('Choose division');
          });
      });

          function showHide(self, show){

              $(".all_teachers_show, .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
     
              if (show)
                  $('.toggle').show();
              else
                  $('.toggle').hide();
              $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
              $(self).prop('checked',true);
          }
          
          function show(yes, no){
              if (no)
                  $('.school').show();
              else
                  $('.school').hide();
              $("region").prop('checked',false);
              $(yes).prop('checked',true);
          }
          
          function school_show(yes, no){
      
            if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked===true){
               document.getElementById('class_label').innerHTML = 'Class:*';
              if (no)
                    $('.teacher').show();
                else
                    $('.teacher').hide();
                $("school").prop('checked',false);
                $(yes).prop('checked',true);
            }
           
            if(document.getElementById("radio2").checked===true){
                document.getElementById('class_label').innerHTML = 'Class teacher:*';
              if (no)
                  $('.class').show();
              else
                  $('.class').hide();
              $("school").prop('checked',false);
              $(yes).prop('checked',true);

            }
          }
         
          function class_show(yes, no){
          
            if (no)
                  $('.class').show();
              else
                  $('.class').hide();
              $("teacher").prop('checked',false);
              $(yes).prop('checked',true);
          
          }
          
          function teachers_show(yes, no){
            $(".toggle, .all_teachers_show,  .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
              if (no)
                  $('.all_teachers_show').show();
              else
                  $('.all_teachers_show').hide();
              $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
              $(yes).prop('checked',true);
          }
           
      </script>   
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#region').change(function() {
                    var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_schools";
                    var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                    $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                        var $school_sel = $('#school');
                        $school_sel.empty();
                        $school_sel.append("<option>Choose region</option>");
                        var schools_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                        $.each(schools_obj, function(key, val) {
                            var option = '<option  value="' + val.school_id + '">' + val.school_name + '</option>';
                            $school_sel.append(option);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
      </script>  
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#school').change(function() {
                    var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_teachers";
                    var postdata = {school: $('#school').val()};
                    $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                        var $teacher_sel = $('#teacher');
                        $teacher_sel.empty();
                        $teacher_sel.append("<option>Choose school</option>");
                        var teachers_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                        $.each(teachers_obj, function(key, val) {
                            var option = '<option value="' + val.user_id + '">' + val.username + '</option>';
                            $teacher_sel.append(option);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
      </script>
      
      </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller check the posted data like this-

```
    if ($this->input->post('radio_button') == 1){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('min_length', 'Minimum Length', 'trim|required|max_length[3]|integer');
           //add more validation
    }
    if ($this->input->post('radio_button') == 2){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('min_length', 'Minimum Length', 'trim|required|max_length[3]|integer');
           //add more validation
    }
```

Comment: I tried with this, but it doesn't show any validation errors. I used:  if ($this->input->post('role_id[]') == 1){  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'name', 'trim|required'); //and so on } I also tried with ($this->input->post('role_id') == 1){  but no errors

Comment: are you tested that your form submitting to your controller function?

Comment: My form validation worked and displayed errors. But now I want to add if definite radio button named role_id with value of 1, 2 or 5 is checked, then to show me only these validation errors for these dropdowns, not for all. Somethnig with  if ($this->input->post('role_id') == 1){ is the problem, which is the way to access it - my radio is named role_id[] ? :)

Comment: can you change your radio button name format and make a radio button group of these three radio with the same name but definitely with a different value?

Comment: I have mede them with name role_id[] and values are 1, 2 or 5. I tested it with var_dump($this->input->post('role_id')); and it shows me this radio value which I've chosed but why validation does not work? And I also can't set value for all dropdowns and radio button - when form submits not to have to choose again. It works for text input, but for dropdowns and radio I couldn't do it. See my code up ;) Could this be because I hide them and use jQuery?

Comment: why validation is not working it's little bit confusing. one thing you can do when one radio button is selected show only it's elements and make display none for other radio button's element and use jquery to do this.

Comment: When user clicks first radio buttons, he sees only that dropdowns, others are hidden. But form validation show errors even on that dropdowns that are not for this radio button. They are hidden but form validation show their errors, how to remove them?

Comment: if you make an element hidden it's value also be submitted by the form. so you need to make display none of these element for not to be submitted by the form.

Comment: They are display none. Thank you for support, I'll continue searching decision...